# Adding "-ing" to a verb ending with a pronounced "e"

Tags: orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, gerunds, silent-letters

When a verb ends with a "e" that is pronounced, do you get rid of the "e" when you add "-ing"?

For example, would you say "His karaoking last night was really unique", or "His karaokeing last night was really unique"?

Comment: I realise I'm asking about the appropriate spelling of a somewhat appropriate gerunding of an inappropriate verbing of an inappropriate form of entertainment, but I couldn't come up with a better example.

Comment: While the question in legitimate, it should be noted that the word given in the example, karaoke is a noun, or adjective, e.g. "Karaoke contest tonight". I've never seen it used as a verb, except in the example given above. "Be", "agree" and "free" are better examples, and in adding "ing", the "e" is not dropped.

Comment: @Brasshat _Karaoke_ is just a noun, not an adjective. In _karaoke contest_, it's a noun adjunct. Just about any noun can be verbed in English, though, so Andrew's example is not particularly far-fetched.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike a case such as "make", in this case the -e represents a vowel in the pronunciation; that vowel remains pronounced when -ing is added, and so there's no reason to remove the -e. Hence: **karaokeing**.

As with a case such a **ski** > **skiing**, you may get a slight yod ([j] sound) introduced, but this isn't represented in the spelling.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably just add *-ing* and retain the sounded `<e>`. This would be the case for the verb *recce*, a clipping of *recconoitre* used in British English. I would write *recceing*. And in your case, *karaokeing*. In the past the hyphen was call into service for such situations (hence *ski-ing*) but we are less fond of hyphens these days.

For the past tense form, you can also add the *-d* the regular way. Again in the past, the apostrophe might have been used. Thus, *karaoked* (or possibly *karaoke'd*) and *recced* (or *recce'd*).